# Ruby on Rails has many relation table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relational-database

I have a table **rb** which has many **interfaces**, then each interface has many **interface_graph_data**. Now my rb interface has_many relation seems to work fine, my only problem is the interface interface_graph_data relation. Here are my models.

```
class Rb < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_presence_of :ip
    validates_uniqueness_of :ip
    validates_presence_of :username
    validates_presence_of :password

    has_many :interfaces
    has_many :interfacegraphdata, :through => :interfaces
end
```

```
class Interface < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :interfacegraphdata
end
```

```
class InterfaceGraphData < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of relation should be `interface_graph_dates`

**upd**:
You also missed

```
class InterfaceGraphData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rb
  belongs_to :interface
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: Ok I have updated it, in the Rb model to has_many :interface_graph_dates, :through => :interfaces and also in interfaces model to has_many :interface_graph_dates when i try to loop through it i get the following error undefined method `each' for #<Interface:0x36f5ad8>

Comment: <%= @rb.interfaces.count %> works but not <%= @rb.interfaces.interface_graph_dates.count %> undefined method `interface_graph_dates' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3632940>

Comment: rb.interfaces.count returns the count of interface_graph_dates for rb. What do you expect rb.interfaces.interface_graph_dates.count to return exactly?